# Update format of a phone number from within journey

Tags: mobile, sms, locale, number, phone

I have a journey that I would like to send SMS messages from and I have already set up Locale and the correct format numbers on a different data extension to test and everything is working as expected.

The problem is, now I am dealing with Data imported via API into a Data Extension which then launches that into a triggered journey. The phone numbers coming through are in the Australian mobile format 0412345678 which means that SMS won't send - they'll quietly error and journey will continue - because numbers need to be in the format 61412345678

So I need to be able to trim that initial zero and add a prefix '61' to have the number formatted correctly for SMS sends?

Does anyone have any idea how to go about this? This update has to take place quickly, right at the beginning of a journey.